# Best way to update product's attribute value

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, model, resource-model

Today I came accross the issue of updating product's attribute programatically in observer on each visit on product page. As it should be really fast in that case I was wondering what is the best way to achieve that.

**First** of all one can get product model, set value on object using setter and save it using `productRepository`. But it is not fast, and it is really buggy on frontend.

**Second** option is using (I think) some methods from `Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource` and there two method that catch my eye here. First one is `_updateAttribute($object, $attribute, $valueId, $value)`, but it is a bit unclear for me - `$object` is for sure product object which is binded with value to update, `$value` means exact value it should be after saving, but what exactly should I pass as `$argument` - instance of what class and do I really need to have id of field in db as `$valueId`?

Method `_updateAttributeForStore($object, $attribute, $value, $storeId)` seems more clear to me. Although I still have to have some object for `$attribute`, but I don't have to provide exact field id - so maybe I should use this one?

Of course both methods are `protected`, so I have to find some class that has access to these methods or create new class with wrappers for that ones.

**Third** way is to create direct query to db using some methods of classes directly communicating with db and `mysql`. I think although it shouldn't be used if possible for many reasons - for example safety of crud operations or breaking of `model` concept.

Comment: U Got solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have used method `updateAttributes` of class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action`. Method can update multiple products and attribute values, but if you want to update just one product with one attribute value you can do it like this:

`$this->action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], ['attribute_code' => $newValue], $storeId);`

Comment: It is worked for me thank buddy

Comment: This is great however does not work for me with tier_price attribute do you know if this is possible with that attribute?

Comment: @harri have you found the solution to update tier_price?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh sorry not really I have done it with direct sql queries that seem to work well however not a magento way.